# How to compare Uint8List in Dart à la nodejs Buffer.compare?

Tags: dart

I am looking to sort a List containing `Uint8List`.

```
var l = Uint8List.fromList([0, 10]);
var l2 = Uint8List.fromList([0, 33]);
```

I want to be able to compare them like in nodejs using `Buffer.compare` ( https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_buffer_compare.asp )

How can I do this in Dart?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any existing implementation.
The documentation for `Buffer,compare` isn't specific about how it orders the buffers.
I'll assume it's normal low-index to high-index lexicographical ordering.

I'd write a function for that as:

```dart
int compareLists<T extends Comparable<T>>(List<T> a, List<T> b) {
  var aLength = a.length;
  var bLength = b.length;
  var minLength = aLength < bLength ? aLength : bLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
    var result = a[i].compareTo(b[i]);
    if (result != 0) return result;
  }
  return aLength - bLength;
}

int compareListsBy<T>(List<T> a, List<T> b, int compare(T a, T b)) {
  var aLength = a.length;
  var bLength = b.length;
  var minLength = aLength < bLength ? aLength : bLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
    var result = compare(a[i], b[i]);
    if (result != 0) return result;
  }
  return aLength - bLength;
}
```

or maybe even using extension methods:

```dart
extension CompareListExtension<T> on List<T> {
  int compare(List<T> other, int compare(T a, T b)) =>
      compareListsBy<T>(thus, other, compare);
}
extension CompareListComparableExtension<T extends Comparable<T>> on List<T> {
  int compare(List<T> other, [int compare(T a, T b)]) =>
      compareListsBy<T>(this, other, compare ?? (a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
}
```